# Broken display website caused by ssl certificate apply

Tags: azure, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

Here is the situation, we try to apply an certificate to our website hosted in Azure with the related contents like js and css are stored in Amazon cloudfront in distributions,

[image: ssl integrated to website]

Once the certificate is applied then the display is broken means css and js are not applied anymore.

[image: The broken display]

When we try to inspect broken elements they are still here, however they are in http mode and not in https the questions are

1. Is that broken display is due to the fact that http is used instead of https
2. if yes which is probably the cause, how can integrate an already purshased ssl ceritficate to my custom website to repair the display

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the browser F12 tools? Why are they not loading? I'm just guessing it's a CORS issue..

Comment: It's almost certainly a mixed (http/https) content problem. The solution may be quite simple, but first, a question: Are you using the default hostname of the CloudFront distribution, e.g. `dxxxexample.cloudfront.net` for the assets?

Comment: Hi jonnas,
I made F12 and check the html output for sources which are located in cloudfront they are still in http and not in https

Comment: Hi Michael, we have our domain name we want to link the certificate to our  domain name the second option in amazon s3 ssl setting yes